# Ruy Lopez exchange variable

Tags: opening, pawn-structure, ruy-lopez

In the exchange variation of Ruy Lopez, why doesn't black capture using the B-pawn? As per good strategy shouldn't we capture towards the center of the board?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

there are a handful of reasons why dc6 gives black better chances than bc6:

1. the d pawn is blocking black's c8 bishop so its transfer to c6 opens the diagonal for our bishop's development and also opens space for our queen
2. bc6 leaves black with a weak isolated pawn on a6 which can be fatal in the endgame
   bc6 is not a horrible move but dc6 is much more precise according to the theory

Comment: I agree with :"2.bc6 leaves black with a weak isolated pawn on a6 which can be fatal in the endgame" but not with:"the d pawn is blocking black's c8 bishop so its transfer to c6 opens the diagonal for our bishop's development and also opens space for our queen" since you only need 1 move  to push the d-pawn to open up your c8 bishop and white in this variation is very much undeveloped so you have the time.